# ViewPager makes camera preview white out

Tags: android, camera, android-viewpager, android-camera, surfaceview

So here's the deal:

I have a custom ViewPager with a Camera Preview fragment and another page, both work fine on their own. The transition between the two makes the camera turn white instead of just maintaining the view. I used a modification to make it a Vertical view pager instead of horizontal.

Before it was vertical, the stock view pager worked just fine. Here's what it looked like before: http://i.imgur.com/eaaHGvR.gif

And now:
http://i.imgur.com/RKxiYZL.gif

What did I miss that's making it go white?

Custom View Pager:

```
public class VerticalPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            //view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            //view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            //view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}
```

}

**EDIT:**
After some tinkering, I got closer, but still crazy amounts of flickering and bugs. Previously, on the horizontal, it had some edge-issues but did not flicker like this:

http://i.imgur.com/aBcreT9.gif

I added view.BringToFront(); in the verticalpager, and also requested transparency when I set the adapter on the pager itself.

Comment: First of all, check if your camera surface view is destroyed.

Comment: My confusion is that I'm not changing any camera code between the two, so the problem must solely arise from the ViewPager, in my adaptation for the vertical. Is there something I need to override so it isn't destroying the page until it's fully out of view?

Comment: The question is whether it *is* destroyed, or there is some other problem. Also, replace the camera live preview with an image view, check that this one behaves correctly.

Comment: Upon a little more testing, it's indeed that the custom VerticalPager seems to call onPause or even onDestroy while that fragment is not in view, or it is being dragged. If I stop dragging but hold it still, it'll activate both fragments, camera stays active, and methods on the other fragment don't fail. But if I start a method on one fragment and switch, it'll crash as it is reading as null (can't find views and such)

Comment: Sorry, just saw your last response. The image views on the page are responding correctly.

Comment: So an ImageView is not destroyed? This could have to do with Camera using much more resources. Also, in light of what you found about "stop dragging", you maybe need some artificial limit that will keep the camera preview just a little bit (even one pixel) on the screen always.

Comment: But why only in the vertical swiper and not the horizontal? Something isn't adding up.

Comment: Maybe the horizontal leaves one pixel strap on the left

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure how that changes things. Even mid drag on horizontal, as you're dragging, it keeps the preview alive.
Wait, I discovered something. There is a thin line of pixels on the bottom that are staying active during vertical drag, so the camera ISN'T being nullified.. Something is being brought to the top OVER it.
It's actually the viewpager being brought up over it, like its being brought to the front. I set the color for the background, and sure enough that's whats covering the camera preview. But when I set it to transparent, something else is covering it now

Comment: You might need [setZOrderOnTop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)) then

Comment: I will try it, but wouldn't that do the same as BringToFront()?

Comment: Still reacting the same way, @AlexCohn

Comment: @JayNoe have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @K.E. unfortunately I cannot remember. I believe I ended up doing an animation of views and just a gesture listener, certainly not ideal or as responsive.